# What projection is this geoTIF and how do I convert it?

Tags: mapbox, geospatial, gdal, mapbox-gl-js, geotiff

I am working with viewing weather data online and the website I use (University of Oklahoma) provides a link to the data displayed as a geoTIF, for research purposes.  [This is a direct link to the geoTIF that I am requesting help with.](http://flash.ou.edu/flash_web/ratio_1h/01H.RAT.20181116.033600.tif)

I am trying to use the image in a Mapbox map, but there seems to be an issue with projection. I use GDAL tools (though I am a novice) and I can't even figure out what projection it is in to start with. When I use gdalinfo, I get the following result :

```
Warning 1: RowsPerStrip not defined ... assuming all one strip.
Raster dataset parameters:
  Projection:
  RasterCount: 1
  RasterSize (7000,3500)
Using driver GeoTIFF
  Image Structure Metadata:
    0:  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
    1:  INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left (-130, 55)
  Lower Left (-130, 20)
  Upper Right (-60, 55)
  Lower Right (-60, 20)
  Center (-95, 37.5)

Coordinate System is:

Band 1 :
   DataType: Float32
   ColorInterpretation: Gray
   Description:
   Size (7000,3500)
   BlockSize (7000,3500)
   NoDataValue: -999
   Offset: 0
   Scale: 1
```

I have been converting other geoTIF files for Mapbox use with the following command successfully :

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 example.tif example-projected.tif
```

... The above code always works except with the file I am needing help with. I am very new with GDAL and though I have been trying it is difficult for me. What am I not doing right and how would I do this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Your geotiff has no embedded coordinate system associated although the corners are obviously geographic coordinates (unprojected). WGS84 is my guess.

My suggestion is defining a source coordinate system in your command [-s_srs srs_def] and see the result,

-s_srs EPSG:4326

If that doesn't work you'd better ask OU. They should know better.

Comment: Would this command be something like you're telling me to do? I am trying to learn alot of things and this has been a weakness. Here is the code : "gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 example.tif example-projected.tif"  - it does not work that way. I just don't know enough about coordinate systems. When I upload the TIF to http://geotiff.io/, their system projects it properly.

Comment: It is not an overwrite issue, so I went ahead and emailed OU. It's a shame this is not working yet. I will see what they say, if they email back.

Comment: For what it's worth, I downloaded the source code for their project and opened up a c++ source code file that deals with projecting the image from the data. I found "PROJECTION_LAEA", which looking online is the Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection. Might this help?

Comment: Well, that is odd. I will just wait on that email.